Next js + styled components hydration error
I'm trying to combine styled components with next js, I created a homepage and wanted to add a footer and navbar, but not only on the homepage but also on other pages. Whenever I add a navigation bar or footer to the layout, I get a hydration error. What was I supposed to do? And what should I give you to help me with my problem?
export default function RootLayout({
children,
}: Readonly<{
children: React.ReactNode;
}>) {
 return (
 <html lang="en">
  <head>
    <link rel="icon" href={icon.src} />
  </head>
  <body className={kameron.className}>
    <StyledComponentsRegistry>
      <Navbar />
      <GlobalStyle />
      {children}
      <Footer />
    </StyledComponentsRegistry>
  </body>
</html >


Disclosure: I'm the author of next-yak
You can solve this by using next-yak instead of styled-component
It's specifically built to handle SSR and RSC issues with Next.js while keeping the styled-components API you're familiar with:
// layout.tsx
import { styled } from 'next-yak'

const Nav = styled.nav`
  // …
`

const Footer = styled.footer`
  // …
`

export default function RootLayout({ children }) {
  return (
    <html>
      <body>
        <Nav>...</Nav>
        {children}
        <Footer>...</Footer>
      </body>
    </html>
  )
}

// next.config.mjs
import { withYak } from "next-yak/withYak";

export default withYak({
  // your next config if any
})

The main benefit is that next-yak extracts the styles at build time - so you don't need a StyledComponentsRegistry and won't get hydration mismatches
Your existing styled-components code should work with minimal changes - just update the imports
